# SQLite Exception: no such column name while compiling: SELECT name, address, number FROM form

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I don't know what will be the fix to the error cause I already mentioned the column names and I have a name column in my database.(I am just a beginner) please help me.

This is my DbH class

```
package sjdb.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by user on 30/09/2016.
 */

public class DbH extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/sjdb.db/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "red.db";
    private static String DB_TABLE="form";
    public static String Col_1="name";
    public static String Col_2="address";
    public static String Col_3="number";

    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                                + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                                + "/databases/";
*/

    public DbH(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist)
        {
            System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        }
        else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try{
                copydatabase();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE) != null;
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }

        return checkdb;
    }
    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();

    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDataBase != null){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    // This will return a cursor containing database records
    public Cursor data(){

        Cursor c;
        String[] from = new String[] {Col_1, Col_2, Col_3};
        c=myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE,from,null, null,null,null,null);
        return c;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And this is my MyActivity class

```
package sjdb.db;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first createdl. */
    Cursor cur;
    TextView tv, tv1, tv2;
    DbH db;
    Button next,back;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);

        try {
            db=new DbH(this);
        } catch (IOException e2) {

            e2.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            db.createdatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        db.opendatabase();
        cur=db.data();
        cur.moveToFirst();

        tv.setText(cur.getString(1));
        tv1.setText(cur.getString(2));
        tv2.setText(cur.getString(3));

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.next :
                if(cur.isLast())
                {
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
                    tv1.setText(""+cur.getString(2));
                    tv2.setText(""+cur.getString(3));
                }
                else
                {
                    cur.moveToNext();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
                    tv1.setText(""+cur.getString(2));
                    tv2.setText(""+cur.getString(3));

                }
                break;
            case R.id.back:
            {
                if(cur.isFirst())
                {
                    cur.moveToLast();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
                    tv1.setText(""+cur.getString(2));
                    tv2.setText(""+cur.getString(3));
                }
                else {cur.moveToPrevious();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
                    tv1.setText(""+cur.getString(2));
                    tv2.setText(""+cur.getString(3));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sjdb.db/sjdb.db.MyActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name: , while compiling: SELECT name, address, number FROM form
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name: , while compiling: SELECT name, address, number FROM form
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1686)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1571)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1527)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
                      at sjdb.db.DbH.data(DbH.java:122)
                      at sjdb.db.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:47)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11719 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
column: name: , while compiling: SELECT name, address, number FROM form
```

Try looking these part. Are these correct?

Try to fit this code if it doesnt go to your TextView.